# Confirming the basic motivation for a sigma algebra (for probability)

Tags: probability, measure-theory, intuition

I just wanted to confirm I have understood to a basic level why we need a sigma-algebra.

When the sample space for our experiment is uncountable, and we are thinking about events, we cannot say that "all possible subsets of the sample space are events," because there are certain peculiar events for that we don't know how to assign a probability to. ("non-measurable subsets of the sample space")

As a result, we take only measurable subsets of the original sample space (= events). Since measurable subsets are closed under complementation and countable unions, we can generate a "universe" which contains only measurable events - **this is what I've understood a sigma-algebra to be**.

Now all events (elements of my sigma-algebra) will have well-defined probabilities and we can continue?

**Addition:**
E.g. If I have $\mathbb R$ as my sample space, then I can use the borel sigma-algebra which is measurable and it practically contains all "nice/normal" subsets of $\mathbb R$ that I would consider calculating probabilities for?

Is this the gist of it?

> **One thing I don't understand is** - I believe the power set is a sigma
>   algebra, however it would contain non-measurable sets if the sample
>   space was e.g. the real line, right? But I think on Wikipedia it says
>   a $\sigma$-algebra is a non-empty collection of measurable sets closed
>   under complementation and countable unions

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra#Measure

Comment: The power set of $\mathbb R$ is a sigma algebra, and there are many perfectly valid measures that can be defined on this sigma algebra. But Lebesgue measure isn't one of them. This is because Lebesgue measure demands several constraints (translation invariance, bounded intervals have finite measure) that are incompatible with requiring the domain of the measure to be all of $\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: @Bungo Right, so part of the reason why we require a "simpler" sigma algebra than $\mathbb P (\mathbb R)$ is so we can use a "simpler" measure?

Comment: @Bungo So when wikipedia says (paraphrased) that a sigma algebra is essentially a collection of measurable events, it means it can be measured be *some* measure - not "all"?

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily call Lebesgue measure "simpler" - after all, counting measure is pretty simple and it can be defined on all of $\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$, or on any sigma algebra in general.

Comment: I would instead word it as follows: if we want our measure to satisfy certain conditions then it may not be possible to define it on all of $\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$, but it may be possible if we restrict the domain to a smaller sigma algebra. Lebesgue measure can't be defined on all of $\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$, but we can define it on a sigma algebra (either Borel or Lebesgue measureable sets) which is big enough for a useful theory of integration and analysis.